# How to supply a Windows batch file with variables pulled from a CSV file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a CSV file with 3 columns and many rows.

I want to run a command in a Windows cmd prompt, and supply input variables to the command from a CSV file, such that:

```
 cd C:\mricrogl
 for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in ('Q:\proc9\Code\dcm2bids.csv') Do Echo dcm2niix -b y -z y -o "%%~A" -f "%%~B" "%%~C"
```

and I need the command to iterate for the length of the CSV file.

The contents of the CSV file looks like this (with no headers) and these 3 columns are the input variables %%~A %%~B and %%~C required by the dcm2niix command.  The command requires the input variables (which are file paths and file names) to be in double quotes.  The command runs when I do one row at a time 'manually' at the cmd prompt, so its the for statement and reading form the CSV file that I cannot get to work.

```
 "V:\Output\folder1", "filename1", "Q:\Input\folder1"
 "V:\Output\folder2", "filename2", "Q:\Input\folder2"
 "V:\Output\folder3", "filename3", "Q:\Input\folder3"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could perhaps add a double quote to the beginning and end of each line whilst replacing each comma with double quote space double quote.

Comment: Append your own code to your edited question and a sample line of your csv file. `for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in ('type your.csv') Do Echo command "%%~A" "%%~B" "%%~C"` is possibly be all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code and sample file that you posted are accurate, then you have two unrelated problems.

**1)**
Your IN() clause uses single quotes, which means the FOR /F will try to execute the csv file rather than simply read the contents.

You must drop the single quotes

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in(Q:\proc9\Code\dcm2bids.csv) do ...
```

If there is a chance that the csv path might sometimes contain spaces, then the path would have to be double quoted, and you would then need the USEBACKQ option

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in("Q:\proc9 with spaces\Code\dcm2bids.csv") do ...
```

**2)**
Your second problem is the leading space before each quoted column value. The `~` only strips outer quotes when the first and last character in the value are quotes. Your first character is space, so the quotes are not stripped.

A CSV should not have leading spaces like that anyway.

If you are in control of the creation of the csv file, then I would fix that code to eliminate the leading spaces, and everything should then work.

Alternatively, you could rely on the quotes being already present in the source. But this only works if you know that the quotes are always present:

```
... Do Echo dcm2niix -b y -z y -o %%A -f %%B %%C
```

If you cannot remove the spaces from the source, and you don't know if the quotes will always be present, then you could use an extra FOR loop for each token to ignore the unwanted spaces:

```
cd C:\mricrogl
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in (Q:\proc9\Code\dcm2bids.csv) do (
  for %%a in (%%A) do for %%b in (%%B) do for %%c in (%%C) do (
    echo dcm2niix -b y -z y -o "%%~a" -f "%%~b" "%%~c"
  )
)
```

Comment: I removed the echo and it all worked.  Thank very much @dbenham